# Regular expression on a string

Tags: java, regex

I have a String like below

```
String phone = (123) 456-7890
```

Now I would like my program to verify if that my input is the same pattern as string 'phone'

I did the following

```
if(phone.contains("([0-9][0-9][0-9]) [0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]")) {

   //display pass
}
else {

   //display fail
}
```

It didn't work. I tried with other combinations too. nothing worked.

Question :
1. How can I achieve this without using 'Pattern' like above?
2. How to do this with pattern. I tried with pattern as below

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\d+)");
Matcher match = pattern.matcher(phone);

```
if (match.find()) {
   //Displaypass
}
```

Comment: You should escape the `(` and `)`. They have a special meaning in regex.

Answer (score 4):

[`String#matches`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) checks if a string matches a pattern:

```
if (phone.matches("\\(\\d{3}\\) \\d{3}-\\d{4}")) {
    //Displaypass
}
```

The pattern is a regular expression. Therefor I had to escape the round brackets, as they have a special meaning in regex (they denote capturing groups).

`contains()` only checks if a string contains the substring passed to it.

Comment: +1. You might want to say something about escaping characters with special meaning in regex.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to dive too deeply into regex syntax, but there definitely is something off with your regex.

```
"([0-9][0-9][0-9]) [0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"
```

it containes `(` and `)` and those have special meaning.  Escape them

```
"\([0-9][0-9][0-9]\) [0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"
```

and you'll also have to escape your `\` for the final

```
"\\([0-9][0-9][0-9]\\) [0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write like:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\(\\d{3}\\) \\d{3}-\\d{4}");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sPhoneNumber);

if (matcher.matches()) {
    System.out.println("Phone Number Valid");
}
```

For more information you can visit [this article](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-validate-phone-number-in-java-regular-expression/).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your problem is that you didn't escape the parentheses, so your Regex is failing. Try this:

```
\([0-9][0-9][0-9]\) [0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]
```

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
String PHONE_REGEX = "[(]\\b[0-9]{3}\\b[)][ ]\\b[0-9]{3}\\b[-]\\b[0-9]{4}\\b";
String phone1 = "(1234) 891-6762";
Boolean b = phone1.matches(PHONE_REGEX);
System.out.println("is e-mail: " + phone1 + " :Valid = " + b);
String phone2 = "(143) 456-7890";
b = phone2.matches(PHONE_REGEX);
System.out.println("is e-mail: " + phone2 + " :Valid = " + b);
```

Output:

```
is phone: (1234) 891-6762 :Valid = false
is phone: (143) 456-7890 :Valid = true
```